# Change database field at specific time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm working on a laravel API and want to activate the users after registration for a month (free trial) then to deactivate them at the end of the month. The activation will be through active column in users table in MySQL db. So, for a user to be activated : active = 1 , otherwise active = 0 .

In registration method I do this : `$user->active = 1;`

**Now, how can I make it be : active=0 automatically after a month ??**

Comment: Write an `artisan` command, and call it daily from your server's crontab. The command should look for all active users created a month ago, who are on a free trial and deactivate them.

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for the artisan command aswell. You might want to consider the timezone differences etc Optionally you can save processing time by running the logic when a user attempts to login. That way you would lazy load the logic and execute when necessary opposed to running it once every day, iterating trough all the users etc

Answer (score 1):

You should add a cron job in your server. This cron job run one time every day, retrieve users having one month after registration and desactivate them.

For linux servers:

You should run the command:

```
crontab -e
```

and add this text for exemple:

```
0 0 * * * php /path/to/your/script.php
```

To run your script every day at 00h00

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to create crone which runs daily. In this crone you have to write script which get all users which are crated month ago and update their status to 0.

Let me Know if you have any queries!